# int to double I think 1050 to 10.50

Tags: flutter, int

been trying to figure this one out for days not, I am using square payments and the amounts are sent as an int 150 is = £1.50p but I am struggling to convert it to £1.50 in flutter.. would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: try to divide with zero and get value in double. for e.g, 1051/100 = 10.51. Very first time convert int value to double so it will like  int:1051, double: 1051.00

Comment: dividing the number by 100 will not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, I believe that this will do the trick.

The package is here: https://pub.dev/packages/intl#-readme-tab-

**Code:**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Converter());

class Converter extends StatelessWidget {
  final currency =
      new NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: 'GBP', decimalDigits: 2);
  final int _money = 150;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Money converter'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Text('${currency.format(_money / 100)}',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**output:** // £1.50

Comment: I am using intl, this is what i was doing within firebase 

const increment = FieldValue.increment(+(requestBody.price / 100).toFixed(2));

but as soon as I get to a round number flutter did not like it as I had value set as double, so as soon as I hit a Int / round number  I get an error ,   cant believe I had the answer in front  of me all along 

Will give it a try now Thank you